# remove cupsd completely from Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, cups

I tried using `apt-get remove cupsd` but I found traces of it in different locations and it is still running and listening. How can I rip it completely from my machine? Is it possible to remove the dpkg for cups?

I am using Linux Mint 17.

`Linux user-virtual-machine 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

```
virtual-machine # netstat -an | more
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15350    /var/run/cups/cups.sock

virtual-machine # netstat -tulpn
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2711/cupsd  
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2711/cupsd 

# find / -name cups
/run/cups
/etc/ufw/applications.d/cups
/etc/init.d/cups
/etc/default/cups
/etc/cups
/usr/lib/cups
/usr/share/doc/cups
/usr/share/linuxmint/common/artwork/cups
/usr/share/doc-base/cups
/usr/share/cups
/var/spool/cups
/var/lib/doc-base/omf/cups
/var/lib/doc-base/documents/cups
/var/log/cups
/var/cache/cups

# apt-cache pkgnames cups
cups-driver-gutenprint
cups-core-drivers
cups-pdf
cups-bsd
cups
cups-common
cups-pk-helper
cups-backend-bjnp
cups-filters
cups-server-common
cups-dbg
cups-tea4cups
cups-ppdc
cups-browsed
cups-filters-core-drivers
cups-daemon
cups-client
```

Comment: Why do you think removing CUPS (Common Unix Printing System)  is a Good Idea? Reinstall the packages you removed,  read the docs (see `dpkg -L packagename` to see the  list of files in the package. If you must, you can disable CUPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list all of your **installed** packages which match 'cups', run

```
dpkg -l | grep cups
```

Then just remove them with `apt-get remove`.

Even after that, there could be some cups processes running. A simple reboot will eliminate them (an alternative would be to manually kill them).

Comment: Some progams link with the libcups2 library, so you probably can't remove *all* traces of cups from your system. Removing the `cups` package will remove the clients and the daemon though.

Comment: when you say `cups package` do you mean these: # dpkg -l | grep cups

`ii  cups-bsd, ii  cups-client, ii  cups-common, ii  cups-core-drivers, ii  cups-daemon, ii  cups-filters, ii  cups-filters-core-drivers, ii  cups-pk-helper, ii  cups-ppdc, ii  cups-server-common`

Comment: yes, these were what I meant. *cups-daemon* looks like the most promising one to remove

Comment: i should of stopped after the cups-daemon. removing the daemon package killed the port and it stopped listening aswell. thank you

Answer (score 8):

3 of the cups packages are used for non-printing things (like pdf conversion); the other 17 can be removed.

```
> cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 15.04 \n \l

> dpkg -l | grep -i cup | grep ii | wc -l
20

> apt-get purge -y cups cups-common && apt-get autoremove -y
...

> dpkg -l | grep -i cup | grep ii | wc -l
3
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 23.04, removing it was using the snap tool:

```
sudo snap remove cups
```

Answer (score 0):

Only can remove the snap cups for existing booted session.  Upon reboot, the snap cups will be reinstalled and active again. Have not found any way to completely stop it from being installed on every boot.

To stop it for the current session:

```bash
sudo snap stop cups
sudo snap disable cups
sudo snap remove cups
```